# css applying a percentage to the height?

Tags: css

In the css code how does the percentage work, 100% of what?

```
.menu-side {
    background-color:#333;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:210px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: 100% of the page containing the element having class `menu-side`